# What is the mass (or density) of the average Jenga block?

Tags: jenga

I am attempting a project in which a robot needs to carry 5 layers of Jenga pieces around a course, while following a line and *without dropping the stacked blocks*. Figuring out the static frictional force needed to move the Jenga blocks off of one another requires certain values.

I already have the coefficient of wood on wood, which is 0.35, but I need **either** the average mass of a Jenga block, or the typical density of the wood used to make Jenga blocks.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just weigh your Jenga blocks? (If you don't have any Jenga blocks, you'll need to get some to test your robot anyway.)

Comment: Quick tip: that formula for friction you learned in school?  It's a lie.  For what you're doing here, it's probably close enough, but don't be surprised if the numbers you get don't match your robot's actual performance.

Answer (score 13):

Well, it looks like that per [Hasbro](https://hasbro-new.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/60/~/what-does-the-word-jenga-mean%3F), an official Jenga set is made of *Alder*, which apparently has a density of [0.38 g/cc](http://www.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/woods.htm), which when combined with the dimensions of a standard Jenga block [from this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8137/are-all-jenga-blocks-of-exactly-same-size) of 1.5cm x 2.5cm x 7.5cm, gives us an average of **10.6875g** per block for a 28.125cm³ block.

The margin of error on both the density (one site I found had a range from 0.4–0.7 ×10³ kg/m³, or 0.4–0.7g/cm³) and the dimensions of the block due to manufacturing tolerances are enough to be considered significant, so I'd add a nice fudge factor to that before running further calculations.

Comment: 0.4-0.7 kg/m3 [is 0.0004-0.0007 grams/cc](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.4kg+per+cubic+metre+in+grams+per+cubic+centimetre). That fudge factor for a 28.125cm³ block is going to be a miniscule one (~0.0011 to ~0.0197 g/cm³). For a tower of 5 layers (15 blocks) that's an estimated maximum 0.2955g difference in weight based on density alone.

Comment: Sorry, fixed my unit notation there: it's 0.4-0.7 10^3 kg/m3. That ends up as 0.4-0.7 g/cc, allowing for up to 1.8x the original as a possible value.

Comment: I've updated the formatting of your notation slightly. Thanks, that makes more sense out of it.

Comment: yeah, if we can get a density of 0.4-0.7 kg/m3 out of something we can use to build Jenga towers, I think the Space Elevator guys want to have a talk about that...

Comment: Well that's the density margin of error (from an average density of 0.38g/cm³ or 380kg/m³) rather than the density itself. :)